# Write to stdout instead of file

Tags: bash

How can I write data to stdout instead of writing file?

I'm using GPG and want to print encrypted text to stdout, without saving files.

However, with gpg command, encrypted text is written to file in ordinary way:

```
$> gpg --recipient someone@example.com --armor --output encrypted.txt --encrypt example.pdf
```

(With above command, encrypted file is saved in encrypted.txt)

What I want to do is like following:

```
$> gpg --recipient someone@example.com --armor --output <STDOUT> --encrypt example.pdf
```

and encrypted messages are shown in console.

I don't want to save hard disk to avoid loss of performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you use "-" to specify stdout, but not all commands accept this and I don't about gpg.

For example:

```
tar -cvzf - foo/ ¦ split -b 50k foobar_
```

will pipe the "tar-file" to stdout, split it and save to "foobar_<123...>".

Answer (score 3):

If your application does not support '-' as a filename (and it should) then an alternative is to use a named pipe, although I'll admit this looks like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut:

```
pipe='/tmp/pipe'
mkfifo "$pipe"

gpg --recipient someone@example.com --armor --output "$pipe" --encrypt example.pdf &

while read 
do
    echo "$REPLY"
done < $pipe

rm "$pipe"
```

Comment: Thanks for additional info :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [gnupg manual](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html)

Simply omit the --output.

Comment: Unfortunately, on my environment, "gpg --recipient someone@example.com --armor --encrypt example.pdf" just generated example.pdf.asc...